# What does syntax like 'FT'[boolean] in Python?

Tags: python

First of all, I'm very sorry that I ask about a fairly basic problem.
When I studying syntactic sugar in Python, I found a very interesting syntax like below:

```
#'FT'[boolean]
print('FT'[False]) # F
print('FT'[True])  # T
print('NY'[False]) # N
print('NY'[True])  # Y
```

As a combination of 'String' and [square brackets],
If a **False** boolean value is entered in [square brackets],
the first character of '**S**tring' is returned, and vice versa, the second character of 'S**t**ring' is returned.

What is the name of this syntax and when did it appear and what is the principle of it?

Comment: `False` equals zero and `True` equals one. So `'FT'[boolean]` is character zero or one from the string `'FT'`.

Comment: because `isinstance(False, int)` and `False == 0` and `isinstance(True, int)` and `True == 1`. So `FT[0]` and `FT[1]`

Comment: @khelwood Wow.. I understood perfectly!!!!!! Thank you for your nice explanation!!!!!!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Aha!! that uses the bool value as an int-type index!!! Thank you very very much

Comment: It's an alternative way to write `'T' if boolean else 'F'`

Comment: @khelwood Wow... Thanks for guiding me with the new syntax  this is called "ternary operators".. very Interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal indexing. What may be confusing you is the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int` (with `True == 1` and `False == 0`) which means that

```
'FT'[False]
```

is equivalent to

```
'FT'[0]
```

which is, of course, `'F'`.

(You might also not be familiar with indexing a `str` literal directly, as opposed to a `str`-valued variable: `print('FT'[False])` is the same as

```
x = 'FT'
print(x[False])
```

)